# the shipment email is not sent

Tags: event-observer, email, shipment

I have created an Observer in order to create and email shipment when an invoice is created.

I am using the `sales_order_invoice_register` event to create the shipment but for some reason I cannot get the email to send...

Here is my code:

```
public function salesOrderInvoiceShipmentCreate($observer)
{
    $shipmentCarrierTitle = $shipmentCarrierCode;
    $customerEmailComments = '';
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    if (!$order->getId()) {
        Mage::throwException("Order does not exist, for the Shipment process to complete");
    }
    try {
        $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment(_getItemQtys($order));

        $arrTracking = array(
            'carrier_code' => isset($shipmentCarrierCode) ? $shipmentCarrierCode : $order->getShippingCarrier()->getCarrierCode(),
            'title' => isset($shipmentCarrierTitle) ? $shipmentCarrierTitle : $order->getShippingCarrier()->getConfigData('title'),
            'number' => $shipmentTrackingNumber,
        );
        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($arrTracking);
        $shipment->addTrack($track);
        $shipment->register();

        $shipment->save();
        $track->save();
        $email=true;
        $shipment->sendEmail($email,’’);
        _saveShipment($shipment, $order, $customerEmailComments);
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
    return $save;
}
function _getItemQtys(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order){
    $qty = array();
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $_eachItem) {
        if ($_eachItem->getParentItemId()) {
            $qty[$_eachItem->getParentItemId()] = $_eachItem->getQtyOrdered();
        } else {
            $qty[$_eachItem->getId()] = $_eachItem->getQtyOrdered();
        }
    }
    return $qty;
}

protected function _saveShipment(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment $shipment, Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order, $customerEmailComments = '')
{
    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
    Mage::log($shipment->debug(),Zend_Log::INFO,'shipment.log',true);
    $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
        ->addObject($shipment)
        ->addObject($order)
        ->save();

    $emailSentStatus = $shipment->getData('email_sent');
    if($emailSentStatus)
        Mage::log("Email has been sent",Zend_Log::INFO,'email.log',true);
    else
        Mage::log("IS FALSE",Zend_Log::INFO,'email.log',true);
    if (!is_null($shipment->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail()) && !$emailSentStatus) {
        $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
        $shipment->sendEmail(true, $customerEmailComments);
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function _saveOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    $order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $order->setData('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $order->save();
    return $this;
}
```

The Shipment is created fine but `the shipment email is not sent` can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be few issues within your code

1. Undefined variable (minor)

   - $shipmentCarrierTitle = $shipmentCarrierCode;
2. Need to use `$this->` prefix when calling a method

> $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment(_getItemQtys($order));
>
> _saveShipment($shipment, $order, $customerEmailComments);

change to `$this->_getItemQtys($order)` and `$this->_saveShipment(..`

Also take a look at [Automatically invoice/ship/complete order in Magento](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/) and [Magento How do I automatically add tracking numbers to an order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276555/magento-how-do-i-automatically-add-tracking-numbers-to-an-order)

```
//START Handle Shipment
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
$shipment->register();

$order->setIsInProcess(true);
$order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically SHIPPED by Inchoo_Invoicer.', false);

$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($shipment)
    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
    ->save();
//END Handle Shipment

 $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
             ->setShipment($shipment)
             ->setData('title', 'Citylink')
             ->setData('number', $track_no)
             ->setData('carrier_code', 'custom')
             ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'))
             ->save();
```